# Is the class of finite sets a pseudo-elementary class?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the class $K$ of finite sets, just bare sets without any structure. Certainly, it is not an  elementary class. Is it pseudo-elementary?

Comment: Nope. Compactness theorem. If a set of first-order sentences has arbitrarily large finite models, then it has infinite models too. On the other hand, the class of all **infinite** sets **is** pseudo-elementary.

Comment: @bof The class of all infinite sets is even elementary: it's $$Mod(\{\exists x_1,...,x_n(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j): n\in\omega\}).$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber Duh. I wasn't thinking. Hm. Well, the class of infinite sets is pseudo-elementary in the **narrow** sense, but it's elementary only in the **wider** sense. I guess.

Comment: @bof Narrow/wide refers to single sentence vs. set of sentences, right? (If so, that's correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move this one off the unanswered queue: as bof observes, the answer is negative due to the compactness theorem. Specifically, by compactness every pseudoelementary class either has a finite bound on the size of its members or has infinite members (and indeed members of arbitrarily large infinite cardinality). So no "class of all finite $X$s" is ever pseudoelementary (unless of course there is a finite bound on the size of the finite $X$s).

Since pseudoelementary classes may look weird at first, let me point out in some detail how compactness can be applied to them too. The general result *(which is overkill here, but important to internalize)* is the following:

> Suppose $\mathfrak{K}$ is a pseudoelementary class and $T$ is a set of sentences such that for every finite $T_0\subseteq T$ there is some $\mathcal{A}\in\mathfrak{K}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models T_0$. Then there is some $\mathcal{B}\in\mathfrak{K}$ such that $\mathcal{B}\models T$.

This becomes more intuitive once we get used to **interpretability**, and realize that being a pseudoelementary class can be reexpressed as "is the class of '$\Phi$-interpretations' of members of some elementary class $\mathfrak{E}$ for some tuple of formulas $\Phi$." The point is that we can relativize the sentences in $T$ to the interpretation $\Phi$; let $T^\Phi=\{\varphi^\Phi: \varphi\in T\}$ be the so-relativized version of $T$. Since each finite subtheory of $T$ is satisfied by some member of $\mathfrak{K}$, we know that each finite subtheory of $T^\Phi$ is satisfied by some member of $\mathfrak{E}$. We now apply compactness in $\mathfrak{E}$ to get an $\mathcal{M}\in\mathfrak{E}$ with $\mathcal{M}\models T^\Phi$. But then $\Phi^\mathcal{M}\models T$ and $\Phi^\mathcal{M}\in\mathfrak{K}$.

In general, your first idea for testing whether something is "first-order describable" in any sense should always be the compactness theorem. (And your second idea should be the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, which also applies to pseudoelementary classes by the same line of reasoning - "push through the interpretation.")

---

As a coda, note that the class $\mathfrak{Inf}$ of all infinite sets is much better behaved. $\mathfrak{Inf}$ is both an elementary class (via $\{\exists x_1,...,x_n(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$) and a "finitely axiomatizable" pseudoelementary class (I don't actually know a term for this, which is to say that it's the class of reducts of models of a single sentence. $\mathfrak{Inf}$ is not however itself a finitely axiomatizable class (since the complement of a finitely axiomatizable class is itself an elementary class).